# Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path)

Tags: android

I recently updated an internal library in our application which is now causing the following error to be thrown on the SplashActivites onCreate method. The resource id `0x7f090053` appears to collide with a color as well, `benchmark_interval_text` is a layout item identifier. I've tried clean, rebuild etc but all result in the same error.

The error occurs during a `super.onCreate(bundle)` call in the SplashActivity.

I recently updated the build.gradle files to compile for API 28.

```
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource "com.example.bundle:id/benchmark_interval_text" (7f090053) is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=5 r=0x7f090053}
    at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:739)
    at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawable(ResourcesImpl.java:609)
    at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawableForDensity(Resources.java:876)
    at android.content.res.XResources.getDrawableForDensity(XResources.java:868)
    at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:818)
    at android.content.res.XResources.getDrawable(XResources.java:790)
    at android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:606)
    at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:463)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:203)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:191)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.checkVectorDrawableSetup(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:753)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:196)
    at android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getDrawableIfKnown(TintTypedArray.java:86)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:260)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:182)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:520)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:71)
    at com.example.bundle.SplashActivity.onCreate(SplashActivity.java:32)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6998)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1230)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2899)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3046)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1688)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6798)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
    at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:108)
```

**Update:**

I've downgraded to compiling against API 27 and found that using `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0` is causing the issue I am facing, but don't why that is. Is there a solution to this so I can once again compile against 28?

Comment: Can you  also show the code?

Comment: Maybe you should post your layout file too.

Comment: There isn't really any code though, all there is is the TextView with id `interval_text` in an activity that isn't called on startup, yet on startup and showing the SplashActivity the above occurs and crashes the app.

Comment: Can you show a pic of res hierarchy  with drawables please

Comment: You are using a View id as a background/drawable. You have to give the drawable a unique name.

Comment: @Twometer not the issue, I have searched the code base for anything like that

Comment: Ok, then it would be helpful to see the layout .xml file, because I can't tell much more than that based on just that exception.

Comment: @Twometer I have edited post with the layout file, but there's nothing extraordinary in there IMO